# CDL File Questions

Tags: data-formats, software, netcdf

I'm confused by what exactly a CDL file is and what its purpose is. [Unidata](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/netcdf/CDL-Syntax.html) specifies the syntax of such a CDL file in its [netCDF documentation](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/netcdf/CDL-Syntax.html).

Questions:
Are CDL files designed to be opened by a simple text editor like Notepad or gedit? Or should I use some other tool to open it?

What is its purpose and how is it used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A CDL file is basically a text output from a netcdf file.  If you want to know the contents of a netcdf file but don't have the time (or ability) to use programs built to read/write netcdf, you can use the simple text output of "ncdump" and then read/write it with a basic text editor.  You can also use "ncgen" to regenerate a netcdf file based on the new CDL file.  I've used this process to make simple changes to netcdf files, and it works very quickly compared to generating a netcdf file using programming methods.

See http://www.atmos.washington.edu/ive/ive_help/writing_netCDF_files.html , quoted below:

> A CDL (network Common data form Description Language) file is an ASCII descripton of the binary data in a netCDF file that is designed to be easily read by humans. CDL files can be generated from netCDF files via the `ncdump', command. For example,
>
> ncdump -c sample.nc
>   generates the file `sample.cdl' that contains the file name, the dimensions, the specification of the variables, any attributes and the data for any "coordinate variables." A CDL file of this type is shown below. Note that the double slash indicates a comment in the CDL file.
>
> netcdf implicit_grid{
>
> dimensions:
>   lon = 101;
>   lat = 101;
>   level = 5;
>   time = UNLIMITED ; //(7 currently)
>   variables:
>
> float A(time,level,lat,lon);
>   A:units = "meters/second";
>   float level(level);
>
> level:units = "millibars";
>   float time(time);
>
> time:units = "hours";
>   //global attributes:
>
> :x_min = -180.f;
>   :x_max = 180.f;
>   :x_units = "degrees_east";
>   :x_label = "longitude";
>   :y_min = -90.f;
>   :y_max = 90.f;
>   :y_units = "degrees_north";
>   :y_label = "latitude";
>
> :z_label = "level";
>   :t_label = "time";
>
> data:
>   level = 1000, 850, 700, 500, 300 ;
>   time = 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 ;
>
> The command `ncgen' is the inverse of`ncdump'; it converts an ASCII CDL file to a binary netCDF file. For example
>
> ncgen -o sample.nc sample.cdl
>   converts the CDL file `sample.cdl' to the netCDF file`sample.nc'. The easiest way to create a netCDF file is to (1) write all the header data (the name, dimensions, variable and attribute specifications, and the values of any coordinate variables) to a CDL file, (2) convert the CDL file to a netCDF file using ncgen, and (3) continue writing the main data arrays to this netCDF file.